# Grails: How to make jQuery-UI work correctly with all its functions?

Tags: jquery-ui, grails, grails-plugin

Hey I just installed jQuery-UI via `grails install-plugin jquery-ui`
And I can't make it work.

I read on the Grails Plugin documentation that I needed to update the file `jQueryUiGrailsPlugin.groovy` and change the `JQUERYUI_VERSION` to the most recent one. I went to change it and it had my same version, so now I don't know what it could be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion, you don't gain enough with this plugin to really make it worth while.  A) You only really need to include 1 js file and 1 css file. Easy.  B) What if you want to upgrade jquery-ui to a new version?  You're stuck waiting on the plugin team to do that for you.

If I were you, I'd just dump the grails plugin all together.  Just use jQuery-UI without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackoverflow is a poor place to ask questions of a new plugin like this one. You'll have much more success asking on the Grails User mailing list since the plugin authors are active there and can quickly answer your questions, and other users will benefit from the discussion.

The link to sign up is at http://grails.org/Mailing+lists